# Form powershell command in Java using java variable

Tags: java, powershell

I have a powershell command in java as  follows:

```
private static final String GET_OBJECT =
        "powershell -Command \"& {Get-WmiObject -Class %s -Computername %s -Namespace root\\%s} | Format-List -property [a-z]*\"";
```

I want to use a separate variable as

```
private static final String GET_CREDENTIAL = "powershell -Command \"& {Get-Credential}\"";
```

and substitute the **GET_CREDENTIAL** in **GET_OBJECT**

How can i do this?

I want something like this

```
private static final String GET_OBJECT =
            "powershell -Command \"& {Get-WmiObject -Class %s -Computername %s -credential  GET_CREDENTIAL -Namespace root\\%s} | Format-List -property [a-z]*\"";
```

Comment: First of all, you should be using a `ProcessBuilder`, this will make your life easier

Comment: i am using Process to run the command  `Runtime runtime = 
Process proc = runtime.exec(Command);
proc.getOutputStream().close();`  this command would be GET_OBJECT

Comment: I am not correct in framing the command using java variable